# Calling .addEventListener(); inside a function fails to actually create said event listener

Tags: javascript, canvas, addeventlistener

I've been using the line
`canvas.addEventListener("click", funcName, false);` without issue for my program, but recently I decided that I would sometimes like to remove said event listener and replace it with another one
`canvas.addEventListener("click", difFuncName, false);`
so I created 4 functions that could be called by my other java script files. 2 functions to add both these event listeners and 2 others that would remove them.

What happens is the function that adds the new event listener calling difFuncName successfully creates the event listener and after the programs through with the listener it successfully calls the remover function. But the problem lies in the fact that the first event listener which is now being called inside of a function is no longer created.

I should note here that before I put the first listener inside it's own function I only had a function with the line
`canvas.removeEventListener("click", funcName,false);`
which also failed to remove the event listener meaning that both event listeners were running their functions.

I've also added console.log("checking"); inside each function to make sure they are actually being executed and all 4 do get run.

So my question is why does one event listener work completely fine when created and removed inside a function but the other one can't be created or removed with a function.

for more context here's the code for my 4 functions

```
function addEventListener(){
    canvas.addEventListener("click", funcName ,false);
}
function removecanvasListener(){
    canvas.removeEventListener("click", funcName,false);
}
function addUnitEventListener(){
    canvas.addEventListener("click", difFuncName,false);
}
function removeUnitEventListener(){
    canvas.removeEventListener("click", difFuncName,false);
}
```

inside javascript *listenerFile*

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var x1;

function funcName(event){
    x1 = event.pageX;
    console.log("doing something on click");
}
function difFuncName(event){ 
    console.log("doing something else on click");
}

function addEventListener(){
    canvas.addEventListener("click", funcName ,false);
}
function removecanvasListener(){
    canvas.removeEventListener("click", funcName,false);
}
function addUnitEventListener(){
    canvas.addEventListener("click", difFuncName,false);
}
function removeUnitEventListener(){
    canvas.removeEventListener("click", difFuncName,false);
}
```

Inside javascript file *changingEventListener*

```
function newListenerNeeded(){
    removecanvasListener();
    addUnitEventListener();
}
```

Inside javascript file *ranafterListenerFile*

```
addEventListener();
```

*ranafterListenerFile* actually loads after *listenerFile*.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable. I'm having trouble understanding the order of all the operations you're doing.

Comment: Can you create a Stack Snippet with the HTML, so we can try to run this and see the problem?

Comment: `ranafterListenerFile` actually what?

Comment: I tried to use snippet but since I don't know how to represent multiple javascript files using snippet, I tried putting it all in one file but the problem doesn't replicate.

Comment: If you have multiple `<script>` tags to load each file, they act just as if you'd concatenated all the files.

Comment: Unless you have them in different places relative to the `<body>` elements, or they use `async`.

Comment: If that's the case then wouldn't a variable called in one script file be accessible in another?

Comment: Yes, it would. There's one global scope, not separate scope for each file.

Comment: I see, I had believed that to not be the case because netbeans would say that variables weren't declared but if I ignored netbeans and still tried to access said variable it would work fine. thanks for the clarification.

Comment: When you're editing script 2, there's no way for NetBeans to know that you're always going to load it along with script 1. So it can't tell that the variables from the other script will be available.

Comment: Thank you I figured out why this wasn't working. I had believed that variables were separate from other javascript files so I actually had two objects saved called canvas. and they were conflicting with each other when I tried executing code using canvas. I suspect the reason I could add a new event listener in one file but not the others has something to do with the order I placed their script reference in the HTML.

Comment: I had a feeling it had something to do with the `canvas` variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Answered in the comments to my question. my problem lies in the fact that all of my javascript code is called in the html at the bottom. because they are all called together they get treated as one large file. My issue spawns in the fact that I was resetting the canvas element as well as the listener later on when I tried to create another canvas object.

Answer (score 0):

It's happening because you named the first function which should add the event listeners **addEventListener**. This will clash with the equally named built-in function.

Try changing the name to something different e.g. **addMyListener**.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

context.fillStyle = "blue";
context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

var x1;

function funcName(event) {
  x1 = event.pageX;
  console.log("doing something on click");
}

function difFuncName(event) {
  console.log("doing something else on click");
}

function addMyListener() {
  canvas.addEventListener("click", funcName, false);
}

function removecanvasListener() {
  canvas.removeEventListener("click", funcName, false);
}

function addUnitEventListener() {
  canvas.addEventListener("click", difFuncName, false);
}

function removeUnitEventListener() {
  canvas.removeEventListener("click", difFuncName, false);
}

function newListenerNeeded() {
  removecanvasListener();
  addUnitEventListener();
}
addMyListener();
newListenerNeeded();
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```